# Largest palindrome that can be made from a product of 2 3-digit numbers (Project Euler 4)

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, c++11, palindrome

This is my solution to Project Euler #4, which asks for the largest palindrome that can be made from a product of 2 3-digit numbers. I have done a brute force method, but it takes around 10-20 seconds to run. It works by looping through 2 variables, finding its product, and converting it to a string to check for palindromity. What steps can I take to improve the computational speed of this program?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
int ans=0;
for(int i=100;i<1000;i++)
    for(int j=100;j<1000;j++)
    {
        int num_to_test=i*j;
        int num_of_digits=floor(log10(num_to_test))+1;
        string num_stringstream;
        ostringstream convert;
        convert << num_to_test;
        num_stringstream=convert.str();
        int counter=0;
        for(int i=0;i<num_of_digits;i++)
        {
            if(num_stringstream[i]==num_stringstream[num_of_digits-i-1])
            {
                counter++;
                if(counter==num_of_digits)
                    num_to_test>ans?ans=num_to_test:ans=ans;
            }
        }
    }
cout << ans << endl;
char quit;
cin >> quit;
}
```

Comment: How should I compile your code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Speeding things up

There are several things you could do to speed things up:

1. Instead of looping from 100..999, go from 999..100 instead.  That way, if you find a palindrome, you can break from the `j` loop because any lower values of `j` will not beat the one you just found.
2. Once you loop backwards, you can also check `i*j` versus the best answer you've found so far.  If `i*j <= best`, you can break from the `j` loop.
3. You don't have to use `log10` to find the number of digits.  Since you are already converting the number to a string, just use `num_stringstream.length()`.
4. The `j` loop can start at `i` instead of 999, because any `j` higher than `i` will already have been tested.

## Cleaning things up

It would make your program look a lot more readable if you moved all of the palindrome checking logic to its own function.

This line here is very hard to read:

> ```
> num_to_test>ans?ans=num_to_test:ans=ans;
> ```

## Putting it all together

Here is what I think your code should look like.  I removed the `cin << quit` part because I wanted to time the program without requiring user input.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

bool is_palindrome(int num)
{
    ostringstream convert;
    convert << num;
    string num_stringstream = convert.str();
    int num_of_digits = num_stringstream.length();
    for (int i=0; i < num_of_digits; i++)
    {
        if (num_stringstream[i] != num_stringstream[num_of_digits-i-1])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    int best = 0;
    for (int i = 999; i >= 100; i--)
    {
        for (int j = i; j >= 100; j--)
        {
            int num_to_test = i * j;

            if (num_to_test <= best)
                break;

            if (is_palindrome(num_to_test)) {
                best = num_to_test;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << best << endl;
}
```

Using `gcc -O3`, this program ran in 0.03 seconds on my computer as opposed to 1.06 seconds, for around a 30x speedup.

Comment: Is it bad to do the hard to read line if I just have an if statement with one command? (compiler wise, not readibility) Also, I really need that palindrome checking in my function instead of outside, because I am organizing my project Euler code as int prob1(){} int prob2(){} etc and additional functions would make a problem harder to find. Thanks for suggesting the reverse loops, they are intuitive and easy to understand.

Comment: @VladimirLenin That hard to read statement was just a `max` in disguise.  Simpler would be `ans = num_to_test > ans ? num_to_test : ans;`.  Or if younhave the macro, `ans = max(ans, num_to_text);`

Comment: Repeatedly constructing the `ostringstream` comes at a cost. Make it `static` and follow with the line `convert.str("")` to get another 30% speed up.

Comment: Also, more importantly for palindromes in general, both OP and this code check every digit twice. Change to iteration to `i < num_of_digits/2` to only check once.

Comment: @Keith Good advice.  I tried the code from 200_success's answer and got a very large speedup also.

Comment: Yes - just checked against my old Euler palindrome code which is closer to that of @200_success and got a 10x speedup. `string` is bound to be slow. Again, the given version arguably over checks the digits.

Answer (score 7):

Your method of testing for palindromes uses floating point (for `log10()`) and stringification, both of which are inefficient.  The following approach should be much faster:

```
#include <cstdlib>

long reverse(long n) {
    long m = 0;
    while (n) {
        ldiv_t divmod = ldiv(n, 10);
        m = 10 * m + divmod.rem;
        n = divmod.quot;
    }
    return m;
}

…

num_to_test == reverse(num_to_test)
```

Note that converting a number to a base-10 string of digits requires a similar sequence of divisions by 10; it's just hidden inside `convert << num_to_test;`.

I've used `long` instead of `int` because `int` is only guaranteed to hold numbers up to 32767, which is not enough for 999 * 999.

Comment: Is there any reason to use the ldiv_mod instead of just taking n mod 10 and adding 10 times to m? Also for me ints are 2^31-1, short ints are 2^15-1? Thanks for the reversing suggestion though, appreciate it.

Comment: When doing `n % 10` and `n % 10`, you're doing two divisions, and throwing away half the work each time. `ldiv()` is supposed to give you both results with one operation.

Comment: `int` is commonly 32 bits these days, but the spec only guarantees that it is at least 16 bits.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert to string, then test whether the result is a palindrome, you can simplify the code quite a bit:

```
bool is_palindrom(long in) {
    auto b = std::to_string(in);
    auto half_len = b.length() / 2;
    return std::string(b.begin(), b.begin() + half_len) ==
           std::string(b.rbegin(), b.rbegin() + half_len);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JS1 provided a great answer, but on my system i got an 80% speed up by using the code i wrote below. My goal was to avoid using strings if possible and stick with integer values.

All of the points made by JS1 still stand, but instead of using

```
bool is_palindrome(int num)
{
    ostringstream convert;
    convert << num;
    string num_stringstream = convert.str();
    int num_of_digits = num_stringstream.length();
    for (int i=0; i < num_of_digits; i++)
    {
        if (num_stringstream[i] != num_stringstream[num_of_digits-i-1])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

to calculate whether or not a number is a palindrome i used a function to reverse the input number using integer operations (its somewhat falsely named palindrome since it technically only reverses any number input into it).

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int palindrome(int x) 
{
    int n = 0;//dummy variable
    while (x) 
    {
        n *= 10; n += x % 10; x /= 10; //this function simply reverses the input x
    }
    return n;
}

int main() {

    //start clock stuff
    std::clock_t start;
    double duration;
    start = std::clock();
    //end clock stuff

    int final = 0; //final is our biggest value found so far

    for (int x = 999; x >= 100; --x) {
        for (int y = 999; y >= 100; --y) {

            const int n = x * y;

            if (n <= final) //if the number being checked is less than the current best then we dont bother seeing if its a palidrome (saves calcuation of reverse of number)
                break;   
            if (n == palindrome(n)) //if the number is the same as the reverse of the number
            {
                final = n; //update best number found
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //print our output
    std::cout << final << std::endl;

    //finish clock stuff
    duration = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    //print time to run program
    std::cout<<"Elasped time: "<< duration <<'\n';

    return 0;
}
```

On my system using integer operations instead of string based ones and compiling with g++ i had an average time of 0.001 for my version and 0.0019 for JS1's version over 10 runs. Using the icc compiler i actually got slightly faster times for both programs, but the difference between them was similar.

Neither implementation is bad, but i think the one i submitted is worth looking at. The reversing done is a lot simpler (in my opinion) and should be faster on your computer as well.